# I am making a Javascript Toggler So I put two images one of night and one of day the night image is not correctly coming

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a Javascript Toggler So I put two images one of night and one of day
the night image is not correctly coming, refer to the following screenshots for those -

[The day is coming just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skkpq.jpg)

[But the image in the night is not coming correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yv7b.jpg)

Here is my html -

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
     #upperpart h1{
     margin-top:12%;
      }
      </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=devicxe-width">
    <title>JavaScript</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body id = "body">
    <div id = "upperpart">
      <center>
      <h1>JavaScriptToggler</h1>
      <button onclick = "tagmahalday()">Day</button>
      <button onclick = "tagmahalnight()">Night</button>
      <center>
    </div>
    <center>
    <img src = "thumbnail.png" id = "thumb"></center>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS -

```
button{
  border-radius:200px;
  background-color:antiquewhite;
  padding:15px;
  padding-left:60px;
  padding-right:60px;
  text-align:center;
  color:Black;
  font-size:17.5px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

Here is my Js -

```
function tagmahalday(){
document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundImage = "url(backgrounds/tjmahalday.jpg)"
}
function tagmahalnight(){
document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundImage = "url(backgrounds/tjmahalnight.jpg)"

}
```

Here are the images I referred to -

Taj Mahal at Day - https://cdn.britannica.com/86/170586-050-AB7FEFAE/Taj-Mahal-Agra-India.jpg

Taj Mahal at Night - https://www.holidify.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/album_pic20.jpg

Comment: did you get it working?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not setting the background-size property.
This code should solve your problem:

```
#body {
    background-size: cover; // or 100%
}
```

Comment: When I am changing the backdrop through jsI want these to apply how can  do it that way?

Comment: If via js: 
document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
The best way is to add styles in advance to your style.css

Answer (score 0):

The image repeats because it is too small. You should find a better image for the night. You can stop the repetition and stretch the image like this:

```
body {
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

But it still won't look good.

Comment: Yeah but how can I do it for the image when the backrop changes

Comment: @KrishnaSingh i cannot understand what you just asked.

Answer (score 0):

Add some CSS, this will fix your problem

```
#body{
  background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
```

}

Comment: How do I do it for the particular background image?

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: @KrishnaSingh you have CSS for button, 
just put this answer in your CSS file and it will solve your problem